# MySQL The "EXPLAIN" statement shows the query with non-left-most where condition uses improper index

Tags: mysql, innodb

Let's say we only have an index idx_abcd, which is (A, B, C, D). There are approximately 30 million rows.

We now have a query

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tableName
WHERE B = ? AND C = ? AND D = ?;
```

The `EXPLAIN` statement of the above query shows the following useful data:

- type: index
- key: idx_abcd
- rows: ~30 million
- ref: null
- filtered: 0.1
- Extra: Using where; Using index

The `WHERE` condition does not follow the left-most principle, but the `EXPLAIN` shows the DB does use the index.

Could it be possible?

The version of MySQL is 5.7. The Engine is InnoDB.

Comment: Don't leave us guessing, what column(s) are in `idx_abcd` and in what order?  It matters, big time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EXPLAIN field `type: index` indicates it's doing an "index scan." In other words, it's traversing every entry in the index. This is also quite costly, perhaps nearly as costly as a table-scan.

But if there are other columns in the table besides B, C, D, the optimizer might estimate that it will be at least a bit less expensive to read every page for that index than to read every page for the whole table.

The EXPLAIN output is a little confusing, because it does tell you that it's using an index, and it even says "Using index" in the extra notes field. We're told that this note means the query is able to get what it needs by *only* reading that index, and it can avoid reading pages of the table itself. This is actually true in this case. It's reading only the index named. But it's reading the *whole* index, not just the subset of the index matching your conditions.

You probably already know why it can't use your index `idx_abcd` for row restriction. Because the index has another column `A` as the leftmost column, it can't assume that the index entries matching your conditions are stored together.

Comment: Yes. There are ~30 columns in the table. It makes sense that scanning 4-col index is cheaper than scanning 30-col table. Thanks~ :D

Answer (score 1):

One possible explanation here is that MySQL has found that scanning (*not* seeking) the `idx_abcd` index is, for whatever reason, faster than just scanning the clustered index of your table.  For this reason, it is choosing to use the index.  Note that the "left-most principle," as you have described it, is not happening here.  That is, because your index starts with the `A` column, it doesn't really help with the `WHERE` clause, which admits any value of `A`.

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming* it is using `INDEX(a,b,c,d)`, that is better than scanning the entire table, but not as good as using

```
INDEX(b,c,d) -- in any order
```

With (a,b,c,d) it needs to read, then not count, rows without the matching b,c,d.

With (b,c,d) or (b,c,d,a), all the rows to count are adjacent in the index.  Furthermore, no unnecessary rows need skipping.

Answer (score 0):

the select column is count(*)，and the where columns are contained by index_abcd，so there is no need to back to table to fetch other data。

keyword: coverd index

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).